# RxJava / RxAndroid: continue range loop after error

Tags: android, range, rx-java, rx-java2, onerror

Here is my sample code with the result:

```
Observable.range(0, 10)
    .flatMap(actNumber -> {
        if (actNumber == 3) {
            return Observable.error(new Throwable("This is an error"));
        }
        return Observable.just(actNumber);
        })
    .onErrorReturnItem(-1)
    .subscribe(new Consumer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Integer number) throws Exception {
            Logs.d("number -> " + number);
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
         @Override
         public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
             Log.d("RX", "Error: " + throwable.toString());
         }
    });
```

> 0, 1, 2, -1

Is it ok, but how can I set it that for this result?

> 0, 1, 2, -1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Thank you,
Robert

Answer (score 1):

According to the Observable [contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html), once an Observable emits `onError` or `onCompleted`, then no more elements will be emitted by the Observable signal. The problem that you are having is that you are returning `Observable.error()` if the number is `3` which will emit an `onError` to your `Consumer` and then terminate the signal.

By the contract, you *cannot* continue a signal after it errors. However what you can do is catch and recover from the error and begin to return a new Observable signal. The documentation for the operator can [be found here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/catch.html).

Here is an example

```
Observable
    .error(new Throwable("error"))
    .catchErrorResumeNext(Observable.range(3, 10))
```

(Note: I did not test this code, but it should point you in the right